# How to terminate the App when the user tries to suspend the App?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, lifecycle, win-universal-app

I am working on a Win phone 8.1(RT), I want to close the application when the user tries to suspend the App(From any page).I know this is an unusual requirement, but I was hoping someone could help me out here.
Currently I have placed the `Application.Current.Exit();` in the `OnSuspending()` of the App.xaml.cs class. It tries to close the App but is unsuccessful.

Code:

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            try
            {
                if (App.localSettings.Values["closeAppOnBack"].Equals("true"))
                {
                    Application.Current.Exit();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to close the application");
            }
            deferral.Complete();
        }
```

Is there any alternative or can somebody point out to me where I am going wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: In what way is that unsuccessful? Is the app actually suspending? It won't do so automatically when debugging. Is the call to Application.Current.Exit being reached?

Comment: Also, you don't need a deferral in this instance since you complete synchronously

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT, the control is reaching at the Exit() method. But the app is getting suspended not closed. And when I try resuming the app its stuck at resuming loading page.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT - Tried removing deferral but no help.